# What is the probability of random walking ant to be at a position after some finite steps on an infinite grid?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-walk

Is it even calculable? What if the grid is infinitely dimensional? Lets say that it is a simple random walk, and probability to move to any neighboring position is equal, but other types are also interesting.

Comment: I think you're going to have to tell us how that ant moves. On an infinite-dimensional grid, the probability is likely to be zero.

Comment: Is the number $$ of steps specified, and we are to find an expression in terms of $n$?

Comment: "Is it even calculable?" Yes, as some explicit sum with explicit equivalent when the number of steps grows large. "What if the grid is infinitely dimensional?" What is this object?

Comment: At which position? How a random walk is defined if there is an infinite number of adjacent vertices?

Comment: Any position on the lattice. Of course positions unreachable in the shortest  path in any given number of steps would have zero probability to contain the ant after that many steps .

Comment: @Euphorbium Why not explain what you think the random walk on an infinite dimensional grid is?

Comment: @Did There is infinitely many adjacent vertices.

Comment: @Euphorbium Precisely. How does one walk on such a graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a finite-dimensional cubic grid, it's possible to calculate the probability that an ant starting at $P$ lands at point $Q$ after $n$ steps, since there are at any time only finitely many positions the ant can occupy, although I don't know a closed form for the probability.

On a cubic grid with uncountably many dimensions: Unless $P = Q$ and $n = 0$, the probability is $0$. For $n = 0$ and $P \neq Q$ the case is clear. So suppose $n \neq 0$. Suppose the ant makes a single step. Since it has uncountably many options, with probability $1$ the ant will not land on $Q$. Instead, it will land on a random point $X$ that differs from $Q$ in at least one coordinate. The chance that this coordinate will never change again is $1$, so the chance that it does change and the ant goes to $Q$ is $0$.

On a cubic grid with countably infinite dimensions, the ant will land on $Q$ with probability exactly $1/6$. Allow me to elaborate: Let $\Omega$ be the set of possible directions the ant can go. $\Omega$ is countably infinite. Consider a probability distribution $P$ on $\Omega$ such that $P(\{\omega\})$ is well-defined for all $\omega \in \Omega$ (i.e. $\{\omega\}$ is measurable for all $\omega \in \Omega$) and there exists a $p \in [0,1]$ such that $P(\{\omega\}) = p$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

By $\sigma$-additivity of probability distributions and by the law of total probability, we have

$$1 = P(\Omega) = P\left(\bigsqcup_{\omega \in \Omega}\{\omega\}\right) = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega}P(\omega) = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega}~p = \begin{cases}\infty & \text{if}~~p > 0 \\ 0 & \text{if}~~p = 0\end{cases}$$

which is clearly a contradiction. So there does not actually exist a probability distribution for the ant's behavior according to your specifications, [therefore any such probability distribution will result in the ant landing on $Q$ with probability exactly $1/6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Answer (score 0):

The probability wont be 0 for sure but the answer will be closer to 0 but it has some value > 0. The probability cant be determined as it an infinite grid and therefore we don't know the value in the denominator.
In general probability of an event is ratio of number of favourable cases to the total number of cases(which here is infinity) and hence we cant determine that value which is for sure greater than 0.

Comment: No the probability can be 0.

Comment: Can you justify?